# How to get the language name in native language?

Tags: python, icu

This is my first time using ICU API, and I'm having a very hard time trying to find out something that I assumed to be very simple: to get a given locale/language name *in the native language* (instead of in English)

Examples:

```
fr    -> Français
en    -> English
pt_BR -> Português Brasileiro, or "Português (Brasil)"
es_ES -> Español Iberico, or "Español (España)"
```

As a reference, in `babel` I can get a given locale name in *any* language, native being the default:

```
>>> import babel
>>> locale = babel.Locale.parse('pt_BR')
>>> locale.get_display_name()
português (Brasil)
>>> locale.get_display_name('fr')
portugais (Brésil)
>>> locale.get_display_name('en')
Portuguese (Brazil)
```

So, how to do the same in ICU? Examples in python are most welcome, since I'm using PyICU, but Java/C/C++ is fine too, since my problem is with the API, and not the language.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just found out: the best method is `getDisplayName()`, but, instead of passing an string as argument, I must pass... a Locale instance!

The complete code goes like:

```
>>> import icu
>>> locale = icu.Locale("pt_BR")
>>> print icu.getDisplayName()
u'portuguese (Brazil)'
>>> print icu.getDisplayName(locale)
u'portugu\xeas (Brasil)'
```

So, unlike babel, Locale methods by default return names in the user's current locale. I must pass the instance itself to get name in native language. So it's easy if you want names in *your* language (in my case, English), but if I wanted in French, for example, I would have to create a new Locale instance of 'fr_FR'. Weird API, but still...

Comment: Not correct. You probably see this behavior because your default locale is English.  Yes, you must pass the instance itself to get the name in native language.  ICU's functions which use the default locale are documented as such.

Comment: Thanks @StevenR.Loomis, I've corrected the answer to reflect this

Answer (score 2):

There is a function `getDisplayLanguage`, which optionally takes the name of another locale. I don't know how the C-api translates to Python, but the relevant C docs are [here](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/uloc_8h.html#a3bf3527de225342853d1fe97503590f7).

---

Glancing over the PyICU-docs, it seems to be something like:

```
locale = Locale("pt_BR")
name = locale.getDisplayLanguage("en")
```

---

Looking at the [wrapper source](http://svn.osafoundation.org/pyicu/trunk/locale.cpp), it seems as if `getDisplayLanguage` takes a zero, one or two-tuple. What about `getDisplayLanguage(("en",))`? I'm not familiar with the PyICU-code base so I'm guessing here.

Comment: locale.getDisplayLanguage() does not accept a string argument, using your code raised `icu.InvalidArgsError`

Comment: Some more research, check my latest addendum.

Comment: Still no good... by the error message, it looks like PyICU is smart enough to convert a string to a 1-tuple, so both 'en' and ('en',) raised the same error: `icu.InvalidArgsError: (<type 'icu.Locale'>, 'getDisplayLanguage', ('en',))`. Anyway, thanks for trying, +1 as I really appreciate the effort and valuable research urls you posted.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <unicode/locid.h>
#include <unicode/ustream.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  Locale l("pt_BR");
  UnicodeString result;
  std::cout <<   l.getDisplayName(l, result) << std::endl;
}
```

☛ `português (Brasil)`

I'm sorry you had trouble with the ICU API. Do you have any suggestion for clarification?

Comment: If I understood your code correctly, you did exactly the same precedures as my answer, but in C++: created a Locale instance and used getDisplayName method passing the locale itself as a parameter.

Comment: And don't worry, your answer was clear enough. It's just weird to see a construct like `x.y(x)`, which seems to be solution in this API

Comment: Thanks. Think of it like `4.add(4)` - the subject and object happen to be the same.  "I talk to myself" (not really). We could add  a convenience function, `l.ownName()` however I'm not sure it adds much.

Comment: "we" as in "I'm an ICU developer"? Wow, nice! :) And yes, I think such convenience function would be nice. But may I suggest `.nativeName()` instead of `.ownName()`?