# List of language names translated into corresponding language

Tags: internationalization, globalization, icu

For my software project, I'm looking for a list of language display names per locale as they are written in the corresponding language, like "Português" in pt_BR or "日本語" in jp_JP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find such data and much more in [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/) (Common Locale Data Repository) or using [ICU](http://icu-project.org) libraries in your software which utilize the data from CLDR. Here is an [excerpts](http://unicode.org/cldr/trac/browser/trunk/common/main/pt.xml#L394) from the data for Portuguese regarding name of languages:

```
...
<language type="ps">pashto</language>
<language type="ps" alt="variant" draft="contributed">pushto</language>
<language type="pt">português</language>
<language type="pt_BR">português do Brasil</language>
<language type="pt_PT">português europeu</language>
<language type="qu">quíchua</language>
...
```

Also, you can check [the demo pages](http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/locexp?_=pt&SHOWCountries=1#Countries) to see the availability of the information through ICU. Getting the name of a specific language according to  a specific locale setting using ICU is simple. Here, I'm quoting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405915/how-to-get-the-language-name-in-native-language):

```
#include <unicode/locid.h>
#include <unicode/ustream.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  Locale l("pt_BR");
  UnicodeString result;
  std::cout <<   l.getDisplayName(l, result) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What platform are you on? If you are on Win32, you want `GetLocaleInfoEx` with `LOCALE_SNATIVELANGUAGENAME`. If you are on .Net, you want the [`NativeName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.nativename.aspx) property on a `System.Globalization.CultureInfo` object. If you are using WinRT, you want the [`NativeName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.globalization.language.nativename.aspx) property on a `Windows.Globalization.Language` object.