# Convert language codes to their native language names in python?

Tags: python

I know how to get the name of a language based on its language code. But I don't know how to get that name in its native form with native letters. For example (south) Korean would be 한국말 or 한국어. Japanese would be 日本語.

```
import pycountry
ko = pycountry.languages.get(alpha_2='ko')
print(ko)
```

Result:

```
Language(alpha_2='ko', alpha_3='kor', name='Korean', scope='I', type='L')
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405915/how-to-get-the-language-name-in-native-language

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [pycountry locales](https://github.com/flyingcircusio/pycountry#locales) with the `gettext` module:

```
import gettext
import pycountry

def get_native_name(code):
    translator = gettext.translation("iso639-3", pycountry.LOCALES_DIR, languages = [code])
    language = pycountry.languages.get(alpha_2 = code)
    return translator.gettext(language.name)

print(get_native_name("ko"))
print(get_native_name("ja"))
```

Comment: Nice workaround.